# D3 - Legend in seperate div element

Tags: d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/inW1NfaUwechJt8C1hC9?p=preview

I'm trying to create a legend for this graph

I can do it by adding the legend to the svg but Id like more control over the styling and position

Is it possible to create the legend in a separate div element and use something like a ul list.

```
var legend = d3.select(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", (d, i) => {
    return "translate(20," + i * 35 + ")";
  });
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You've got 2 options. If you're trying to use `rect` and `text` as legends, they cannot be a part of a `ul` but you'll have to have a **separate** svg and append `g.legend` to that and have control over it OR if you WANT to use an `ul`, then use `div` for `rect` and `span` for `text` and append simple `<li>`s. Let me know whichever option you'd like and I can help with you that.

Comment: I think I want to go the div and span direction so I can have more control over styling with CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Based on your comment it appears as though a html list approach is what you want, I'll answer for that approach.

Rather than appending a `g` for each legend item, append `li` to a list. You can also append the `div` and `ul` with d3, just as any svg component. The only major change is appending the right type of element and setting its relevant properties - as this will be different with html than svg.

As with svg components, you can style with css or .attr/.style methods (I use both below).

Here's an example:

```js
var data = [{"name":"Category 1", "value":1},{"name":"Category 2", "value":2},{"name":"Category 3", "value":3},{"name":"Category 4", "value":4},{"name":"Category 5", "value":5}];

var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range(["red","orange"])
  .domain([1,5]);
  
var divLegend = d3.select("#divLegend");

divLegend.append("p")
    .html("Legend Title")
    .style("text-align","center")
    .style("font-size","20px")

var list = divLegend.append("ul");

var entries = list.selectAll("li")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("li");
  
  
// append rectangle and text:
entries.append("span")
  .attr("class","rect")
  .style("background-color", function(d) { return scale(d.value); })
  
entries.append("span")
  .attr("class","label")
  .html(function(d) { return d.name; })
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.rect {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.label {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#divLegend {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="divLegend"></div>
```